# What type of Google tracking should I use?

Tags: multisite, google-analytics

I have WP Multisite and now I want to track the different sites.
I'm using Multisite Domain Mapping to map `www.mysite.com` to `http://subsite.mysite.com`

My questions is:

**a)** Do I need to add the same google analytics script to all themes?
**b)** when creating the script at GA, I have the following choices:

- A single domain (default)
- One domain with multiple subdomains
- Multiple top-level domains

Do I use nr 2 or 3?

I know there are plugins I can use. But I still have to create the scripts at GA, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hook the script into the footer, which is easy enough.

http://wpmututorials.com/plugins/how-to-hook-into-the-footer/

As stated in the post, toss that into mu-plugins, it will track all your site, regardless of domain. GA can sort it out on their end.

totally do-able.

Comment: Hi Andrea. Nice to see you here :) Yup - didn't think of that. Knew it was an easy way to do this. And I bet I'll go for # 3.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the right setup at GA first. There is an option where you select if you want to use it on a single domain or on multiple domains. Please see the description there as it depends on what you want to do on your site - and you have multiple options.

After you've made your mind about how you want to have it configured you should select the appropriate plugin and configuration. I don't know from top of my head which of the many is fitting for a multi-site multi-domain setup. Probably other readers can share some practical experience for a recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

GA operates with profiles, that is entity that you choose to view report for.

Choice between 2 and 3 is essentially choosing if you want to combine all of domains under single profile/report (but be able to distinguish sub-domains with filters and such) or you want completely separate profiles.

See [My site has multiple domain names. How do I set up tracking?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55570).